# NSFetchedResultsController does not react on update

Tags: core-data

Today I've faced a very strange behavior of NSFetchedResultsController which I use to fill UITableView with Core Data records.

I have two entities in Core Data model: `Parent` and `Child`. Each entity has Int16 attribute `typeNumber` and string attribute `name`. `Parent` has to-many relationship to `Child` called `children`.
NSFetchRequest for NSFetchedResultsController selects `Child` entities sorted by `name` with predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent.typeNumber == 1"]`. Looks very simple.

Before NSFetchedResultsController performs fetch there is a following structure in CoreData: one `Parent` with `typeNumber = 1` named `parent1` with two children: `child1` (name) with `typeNumber = 1` and `child2` with `typeNumber = 2`. So right after `performFetch` it shows those two `child1` and `child2. So far so good.

But then following action is triggered: new `Parent` object is added to the same `NSManagedObjectContext` with `typeNumber = 1` named `parent2` and with two children: `child3` with `typeNumber = 1` and `child4` with `typeNumber = 2`. This fires `controller: didChangeObject: atIndexPath: forChangeType: newIndexPath:` selector of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol two times. Now I see all 4 children in UITableView. Ok.

Then I change `parent1.typeNumber` to `2` with following code: `parent1.typeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];`. But no `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`selectors are fired! How's that? Now `child1` and `child2` won't match `NSFetchedResultsController` fetchRequest, right? Why `NSFetchedResultsController` did not react on that? I thought it somehow knows when properties of NSManagedObject subclasses that used by CoreData are changed.

Comment: Sources of a test project are [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1403697/CoreData%20test.zip)

Comment: I actually know a workaround this situation: just call `NSFetchedResultsController performFetch` and `tableView reloadData`. But curious why `NSFetchedResultsController` is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the access form e.g.

```
parent1.typeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
```

... if you have created a custom `Parent` subclass of NSManagedObject and instantiated the `parent1` object as that subclass. Otherwise, the `parent1` is just a generic NSManagedObject and you have to make a change with key-value coding:

```
[parent1 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"typeNumber];
```

If you don't use the proper access form, the changes are actually never made so the controller never sends its delegate the change messages.

Comment: Yes, of course both `Child` and `Parent` classes are inherited from NSManagedObject. I've just used automatic class generation from xcdatamodel in XCode.